# Is it possible to transform salary data so that it can be input into arcsin(x)?

Tags: r, transformation

I have data on annual salaries. Summarized:

> Min: 61915
>   Median:102499
>   Mean: 107973 Max: 218071

I want to apply the arcsin tranformation to this data. In R, with the metafor package installed, I run:

```
transf.arcsin(annsal)
```

but get the following error message:

```
> transf.arcsin(wages$annsal)
  [1] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [21] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [41] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [61] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [81] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[101] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[121] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[141] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
[161] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Warning message:
In asin(sqrt(xi)) : NaNs produced
```

I know the domain for arcsin(x) is (-1,1). Is there a way for me to transform my annual salary data so that it may be input into the arcsin transformation in R?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do a simple scaling transformation?

Since you don't want values of -1 or +1 exactly, you can offset the max and min of the range by some small positive amount that is appropriate for you such as eps (epsilon) = .0001

```
salaries <- rnorm(100,0,1)

y <- range(salaries)

eps = .0001

z <- (salaries - (y[1] - eps) ) * 2 / ( (y[2] + eps) - (y[1] - eps)) - 1
```

z gives you data on the scale [-1 to 1]

Alternatively if you are prepared to drop the min and max values [which will be +1 and -1 according to the above transform] (they may or may not be unique min and max values too), you could do the more simple situation

```
z <- (salaries - y[1] ) * 2 / ( y[2] - y[1]) - 1
```

Comment: I'll certainly give this a shot once I go through it. Thank you very much for your help!